# Linked list insert end node in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm currently learning about linked list in C and trying to write a function to insert a node at the end and then print all the data.

At first my function did not work (only 1 2 are printed)

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void add_end(struct node *head, int a){
    struct node *current, *temp;
    current = head;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = a;
    temp->link = NULL;
    while(current != NULL){
        current = current->link;
    }
   current = temp;
};

int main()
{
struct node *head;
head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->data = 1;
head->link = NULL;

struct node *current;
current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
current->data = 2;
current->link = NULL;

head->link = current;

add_end(head, 3);

current = head;

while(current != NULL){
    printf("%d\n", current-> data);
    current = current->link;
    }

return 0;
}
```

After a while fixing it worked ( 1 2 3 are printed )

```
void add_end(struct node *head, int a){
    struct node *current, *temp;
    current = head;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = a;
    temp->link = NULL;
    while(current->link != NULL){
        current = current->link;
    }
   current->link = temp;
};
```

Can anyone tell me why the first one did not work pls. I thought they are the same because in the first version: current is the link of the last node which is the address of the next node (null) and in the second version: current->link is the link of the last node, which is the address of the next node (null) as well.

Comment: The first one doesn't work because the final assignment to `current` makes absolutely no changes to the list itself; all it does is change what the local variable `current` is pointing to. After that, the function exists and the allocated memory is leaked.  And the second will only work if `head` refers to an initial node on function inception. Sans that, it won't work either (and in fact will invoke undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Once `current` is `NULL` you have already passed the last node in the list, and `current` is a `NULL` pointer.

Assigning to it will not add the node to the list, it will just reassign `current` to no longer be a `NULL` pointer, but the last nodes `link` will not have been modified.

With the second function you find the actual last node in the list, and append the new node to the end.